# Subviews clipping when deleting custom UITableViewCell

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiview, uiviewanimation

I've been working on this for a bit today and can't figure out a proper fix. I could get really hacky with custom animations on the cell, but that would be dirty. I can't figure out why this issue is occurring in the first place.

[Here's a video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NS3kIPEkUUA) of the problem. (note that I've slowed down animations so its super clear)

I'm making a custom `UITableViewCell` based on [MCSwipeTableViewCell](https://github.com/alikaragoz/MCSwipeTableViewCell)'s setup. Here's the basic setup when swiping/deleting:

```
UITableViewCell
    Cell Screenshot
    Color View
        Button Container
            Button
            Button
            Button
    ContentView
```

The screenshot view is the one that is animated when swiping. The button container is what swipes the buttons off the screen. Finally, the color view is the view that changes the background color.

I've tried with all of the different `UITableViewRowAnimation`s, with Fade being the best looking, but its not exactly what I want.

I've also tried adding the **Color View** to the content view and background view, nothing changes.

Here's what the view creation looks like currently:

```c
_buttonColorView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds];
_buttonColorView.backgroundColor = self.defaultColor ?: [UIColor clearColor];
[self addSubview:_buttonColorView];

_slidingView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds];
[_buttonColorView addSubview:_slidingView];

_contentScreenshotView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:contentViewScreenshotImage];
[self addSubview:_contentScreenshotView];
```

And here's the super-simple deletion code, which fires in a delegate callback for the cell swipe animation:

```c
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];

[self.items removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationBottom];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

**edit:** The hack I'm talking about is this. Used with a Fade animation it is decent, though not perfect.

I added this method to the custom cell:

```c
- (void)commitDeleteAnimations:(UITableViewRowAnimation)rowAnimation {
    CGRect frame = self.buttonColorView.frame;

    if (rowAnimation == UITableViewRowAnimationTop) {
        frame.origin.y = frame.size.height;
        frame.size.height = 0;
    }
    else {
        frame.size.height = 0;
    }

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
        self.buttonColorView.frame = frame;
        self.contentView.frame = frame;
    }];
}
```

And then when deleting, do this:

```c
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];

[self.items removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
[self.tableView endUpdates];

[cell commitDeleteAnimations:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

Again, very hacky.